# Dask Dataframe View Entire Row

Tags: python-3.x, dask

I want to see the entire row for a dask dataframe without the fields being cutoff, in pandas the command is `pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', -1)`, is there an equivalent for dask? I was not able to find anything.

Answer (score 2):

You can import pandas and use `pd.set_option()` and Dask will respect pandas' settings.

```
import pandas as pd

# Don't truncate text fields in the display
pd.set_option("display.max_colwidth", -1)

dd.head()
```

And you should see the long columns. It 'just works.'

Comment: For me with pd 2.2.1, this gives: `ValueError: Value must be a nonnegative integer or None`

Comment: @climatestudent can you please try this? `pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', None)` and I will update if it works.

Answer (score 0):

Dask does not normally display the data in a dataframe *at all*, because it represents lazily-evaluated values. You may want to get a specific row by index, using the `.loc` accessor (same as in Pandas, but only efficient if the index is known to be sorted).

If you meant to get the whole list of columns only, you can get this by the `.columns` attribute.

Comment: what if I just what to view one row, not the entire data set. My goal is to view the format of one url cell in my data just to see everything it contains

Comment: use `.head(1)` ?

Comment: @mdurant Uhhh right, but we need to see the actual data in its entirety, or more than the default value. Without `display.max_colwidth` we can only see a tiny part of text. This is an enormous problem for doing NLP with Dask. I posted the right answer below.

Comment: Any idea how to do the equivalent with xarray Dask Array?

Comment: Use `sel()` or `.isel`. Only the partition you select should be loaded.